# CSS border radius on outer container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have a little issue with some css border radius.

I'm using Bootstrap 3 with the .navbar-nav etc and I need the container to have a border radius like the nav buttons but I have no idea where to start on this. Be very grateful if someone can point me in the right direction! Thanks in advance

[image]

As you can see the outer section is squared off but I need it rounded like the nav buttons.

What I'm trying to get:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Who we are</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">What we do</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Construction</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Planned maintenance</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Our responsibilities</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.navbar-collapse {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ff6b00;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  border:0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
  background:#092c74;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #FFF;
  background:#ff6b00;
  padding-left:20.9px;
  padding-right:20.8px;
  margin:0 1.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  transition: all .2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .1s linear;
  -o-transition: all .1s linear;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:first-child a {
  margin-left:3px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:last-child a {
  margin-right:3px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #c85400;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #092c74;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: I am confused. You want the .container class to have a border-radius? Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: me too, you want the dark blue to round?

Comment: Like this ? http://www.bootply.com/CmJ6W8hwdJ

Comment: Do you mean on the top edge of the container(blue)?...you should do this http://jsfiddle.net/bcc1zdzu/ . Add this rule on the .navbar-default  and .navbar-nav {radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;}

Comment: Yes, check @Danko's bootply.  I think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi guys sorry about the confusion, I've updated the post to show what I have/what I'm trying to get.

Cheers for all the super fast replies!

Comment: @Danko Similar to that but with the curves going the opposite way (out not in)

Comment: I still have no idea what you are trying to achieve.   Draw it in paint.

Comment: What's the difference between the two pictures besides the icon?

Comment: Hi all, you see the outside orange parts, their outside of the navbar-nav. I'm trying to get the rounded corners for those instead of the square corners but because their not nav items I'm not sure how to go about it. Maybe a before/after background image on the navbar-nav?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cheers for the help I've managed to figure it out. Using :before :after

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav:before {
  width:5px;
  height:5px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:10px;
  background:#ff6b00;
  background-image:url('../images/top-right-radius.png');
  background-position: top right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav:after {
  width:5px;
  height:5px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:10px;
  background:#ff6b00;
  background-image:url('../images/top-left-radius.png');
  background-position: top right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { .navbar-default .navbar-nav:before { display:none; } .navbar-default .navbar-nav:after { display:none; } }
```

Seems ugly but working nonetheless, would love to hear if there's better ways to do it. Again, thanks everyone for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: Please tick the answer as answered else more people would be unnecessarily directed to answer it.